# why does printf auto convert %x %o %d to hex oct and dec

Tags: c

Some how I thought this should have worked.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{   
     short i;
     scanf("0x%hi",&i);
     printf("0x%x\n",i);
     printf("0%o\n",i);
     printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

Wonder why ?Any answers , why this doesnt work. I thought this should auto do the conversion into hex oct and atleast it should print the decimal correctly

```
  32768
  0x26
  046
  38
```

Is what I get for 32768 input .

Comment: `void main(void)` is wrong. Use `int main(void)`. If your textbook tells you to use `void main(void)`, ask for your money back. See the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/), section 11, starting with question 11.12a. (Note: Saying it's "wrong" is a slight oversimplification, but it's close enough for now.)

Comment: What you should be getting is '32768 0x0 00 0'. So I'm interested in why you're getting the results you quote. What platform and compiler are you using?

Comment: There is seldom any real benefit to using *short* over *int*. Avoid unless there is a provable benefit to shortening your integers. Bits are cheap, bugs are expensive.

Comment: @DavidGiven: There is no "should" here. If you use `scanf` with numeric input, and you give it a value outside the range of the target type, the behavior is undefined. See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.21.6.2p10; earlier versions of the standard have the same rule.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Ah, yes; pure coincidence that on my platform it was initialising i to 0, which was confusing me. Thanks for the ref.

Answer (score 4):

`short` is probably 16-bit on your platform, in which case `32768` doesn't fit.  Try using a bigger type instead.

Demo: http://ideone.com/D0hzP.

Comment: Or a smaller value, like `32767`.

Comment: Just to clarify: if you give scanf a number that doesn't fit, it will leave the variable undefined and probably full of garbage. It's always worth checking the return value of scanf and friends.

Answer (score 0):

sorry , I did a silly mistake. But it really helps and gives courage and comfort when u ask a question.

```
      scanf("%hi",&i);
```

Removing 0x fixed this. Thanks for the help all of you.